# javafx add component from another class

Tags: javafx

I want to add textboxes to a FXML page from another class in my model .
Is it only possible to add components through a controller ?

The function I want to do is such that when the method is run in the model class, a textbox is added to the FXML.

Edit:

I have a Chat.fxml that contains a gridpane, a model class Chat.java and a ChatController.java .
I want to programme Class.java to contain a method that adds a textbox to the gridpane in Chat.fxml . 
How do you code it ?

Comment: Let's make this less theoretical.  Edit the question to provide an [mcve].

Comment: Since your question has no code, then I can only tell you this is possible as long you have the reference of the `Stage`, `Scene` or any `Node` that is in the same scene graph as any `Node` defined in the FXML.